# SQL Counting and Joining

Tags: sql, join, count

I'm taking a database course this semester, and we're learning SQL.  I understand most simple queries, but I'm having some difficulty using the count aggregate function.

I'm supposed to relate an advertisement number to a property number to a branch number so that I can tally up the amount of advertisements by branch number and compute their cost.  I set up what I think are two appropriate new views, but I'm clueless as to what to write for the select statement.  Am I approaching this the correct way? I have a feeling I'm over complicating this bigtime...

```
with ad_prop(ad_no, property_no, overseen_by) as
  (select a.ad_no, a.property_no, p.overseen_by
   from advertisement as a, property as p
   where a.property_no = p.property_no)
with prop_branch(property_no, overseen_by, allocated_to) as
  (select p.property_no, p.overseen_by, s.allocated_to
   from property as p, staff as s
   where p.overseen_by = s.staff_no)

select distinct pb.allocated_to as branch_no, count( ??? ) * 100 as ad_cost

from prop_branch as pb, ad_prop as ap
where ap.property_no = pb.property_no
group by branch_no;
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you @PortableWorld for formatting my code properly!

Comment: No problem. Common oversight. I just wish I knew the answer to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify it like this:

advertisement
 - ad_no
 - property_no

property
 - property_no
 - overseen_by

staff
 - staff_no
 - allocated_to

```
SELECT s.allocated_to AS branch, COUNT(*) as num_ads, COUNT(*)*100 as ad_cost 
FROM advertisement AS a
INNER JOIN property AS p ON a.property_no = p.property_no
INNER JOIN staff AS s ON p.overseen_by = s.staff_no
GROUP BY s.allocated_to;
```

Update: changed above to match your schema needs

Answer (score 0):

i can tell you that you are making it way too complicated. It should be a select statement with a couple of joins. You should re-read the chapter on joins or take a look at the following link

http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp

A **join** allows you to "combine" the data from two tables based **on** a common key between the two tables (you can chain more tables together with more **joins**). Once you have this "joined" table, you can pretend that it is really one table (aliases are used to indicate where that column came from). You understand how aggregates work on a single table right?

I'd prefer not to give you the answer so that you can actually learn :)

Comment: So I join the three tables based on their common attributes, group by the branch_id, then count the occurrences of each branch_id?

Comment: yep :) sounds like you understand it now

Comment: Thanks, I am starting to understand the concepts a little better today!

Answer (score 0):

You can condense your WITH clauses into a single statement.  Then, the piece I think you are missing is that columns referenced in the column definition have to be aggregated if they aren't included in the GROUP BY clause.  So you GROUP BY your distinct column then apply your aggregation and math in your column definitions.

```
SELECT
   s.allocated_to AS branch_no
  ,COUNT(a.ad_no) AS ad_count
  ,(ad_count * 100) AS ad_cost
...
GROUP BY s.allocated_to
```